# find indices of non zero elements in matrix

Tags: r

I want to get the indices of non zero elements in a matrix.for example

```
X <- matrix(c(1,0,3,4,0,5), byrow=TRUE, nrow=2);
```

should give me something like this

```
row col
1    1
1    3
2    1
2    3
```

Can any one please tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
which(X!=0,arr.ind = T)
     row col
[1,]   1   1
[2,]   2   1
[3,]   1   3
[4,]   2   3
```

If `arr.ind == TRUE` and `X` is an array, the result is a matrix whose rows each are the indices of the elements of `X`

Comment: T stands for TRUE here. For those of you new to R, you could also write `which(X!=0,arr.ind = TRUE)` and get the same effect.

Answer (score 10):

There's an error in your example code - True is not defined, use TRUE.

```
X <-matrix(c(1,0,3,4,0,5), byrow = TRUE, nrow = 2)
```

which should do it:

```
which(!X == 0)
X[ which(!X == 0)]
#[1] 1 4 3 5
```

to get the row/col indices:

```
 row(X)[which(!X == 0)]
 col(X)[which(!X == 0)]
```

to use those to index back into the matrix:

```
   X[cbind(row(X)[which(!X == 0)], col(X)[which(!X == 0)])]
   #[1] 1 4 3 5
```